A simple constrained optimization problem
Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $E(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n (v_i^2-1)^2$ be the energy to be minimized. Define the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i = cn$. This means the average value of all $v_i$'s is $c$. Suppose $c> 1$.
My approach: intuitively, we know that $E$ "wants" the values $v_i$ to be near $-1$ and $1$. But because of the constraint, suppose the values of $v$ are closer to $1$. We need to decide how the deviations from $1$ are distributed -- are they all concentrated onto one $v_i$, or are they "spread out" over all the $i$'s? It would make sense that they are spread out onto all the $i$'s because the cost is quadratic in the deviation from $1$. It's better off if two $v_i$'s deviate by half the excess than if one $v_i$ deviates by all the excess.
How do I formalize this though? I want to use the fact that $E$ is convex in $v_i$ when $v_i >1$, so that it's better to replace two values by their average. Thus, all values averaging out will end up being constant. However, $E$ is not convex everywhere.
Attempt with Lagrange multiplier: the augmented equation would be
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (v_i^2-1)^2 + \lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i - cn\right)\,. $$
The EL equation would be
$$ v_i^3-v_i = \lambda \, \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n v_i = c n\,.$$
Is that right? How would you solve this?

Hint: Lagrange multiplier. Get your hand dirty and solve them directly is the way to go.
Let $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, from what you have, i.e.,
$$
g(v, \lambda)
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (v_i^2 - 1)^2 + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i - cn\right),
$$
we solve $\partial_v g(v, \lambda) = 0$ and $\partial_\lambda g(x, \lambda) = 0$. The latter is exactly what you have, i.e., $\sum_{i}v_i = cn$, while the former basically gives
$$
\frac{\partial g(v, \lambda)}{\partial v_i} 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial v_i} ((v_i^2 - 1)^2 + \lambda v_i)
= \frac{\partial}{\partial v_i} (v_i^4 - 2v_i^2 + 1 + \lambda v_i)
= 4 v_i^3 - 4 v_i + \lambda = 0,
$$
for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Solving for $v_i$, You can conclude that if $v_i \in \mathbb{R}$, then $v_i$ indeed has a closed-form (depends only on $\lambda$, not $i$). For example, WolframAlpha gives:

You see that the solution of $v_i$ is the same for all $i$, so let's denote $v_i = v(\lambda)$. If $\lambda$ is large, then $v(\lambda)$ is unique, then the second equation becomes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n v_i = cn 
\implies n v(\lambda) = cn 
\implies v(\lambda) = c.
$$
This conclude the proof, i.e., $v_i$'s indeed need to be the same, and more specifically, $c$. On the other hand, when $\lambda$ is small, you'll need to work with potentially three roots of $v(\lambda)$, which is probably too complicated to work out. But it is what it is.

thanks. I added an attempt to the question; would you take a look?

@900edges I think you make a mistake at first: your Lagrangian should be $\sum_i (v_i^2 - 1)^2 + \lambda (\sum_i (v_i - c))$, not $\sum_i (v_i^2 - 1)^2 + \lambda (\sum_i v_i - c)$ since your constraint is $\sum_i v_i - cn = 0$.

why should the constraint be on every individual $v_i$? The constraint is $\sum_i v_i = cn$ so should give the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda\big(\sum_i v_i - cn\big)$, right? I can see how this becomes $\lambda \big(\sum_i (v_i - c) \big)$ but what is the reason for writing it that way?

It's just because you initially wrote $\sum_i v_i - c$ and I assume you missed the parenthesis.

oh i see. i edited the post.

@900edges I edit my answer with a full calculation since there are other mistakes you made.

thank you for the details. I am still a bit unsure though, since the cubic $x^3-x = \lambda$ has one or three possible real solutions (if $|\lambda|$ is small enough then there are three). How can you say that there is only one solution?

Yes you're right. I'm not being rigorous there but I guess that's something you will need to deal with in that regime. Since I'll imagine otherwise you don't get such a nice closed-form. With that being said, $v_i$'s are still the same (in terms of solution sets), so, you can probably check whether there's other combination that can give you $\sum_i v(\lambda)^{(k)} = cn$ for $k = 1, 2, 3$, corresponding to 3 possible solutions.

I think this is the key barrier to showing that $v_i$ are constant though.

I mean, as you can see, you can't really do much about it. You will need to work with this complicated form at the end of the day.

From
$$
 v_i^3-v_i = \lambda \, \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n v_i = c n
$$
we have
$$
\sum_i^n v_i^3-\sum_i^n v_i - n\lambda = \sum_i^n v_i^3-c n - n\lambda = 0
$$
and from
$$
v_i^3-v_i = \lambda \Rightarrow v_i = \phi(\lambda)\ \ \forall i
$$
so whe have
$$
n \phi(\lambda)^3-c n-\lambda n = 0\Rightarrow \phi(\lambda)^3-\lambda = c\Rightarrow \lambda = \psi(c)
$$
and finally
$$
v_i = \phi\left(\psi(c)\right)
$$
NOTE
Supposing that the polynomial $ v_i^3-v_i = \lambda$ has only one real root I got to this point:
$$
v_i = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda \right)^{2/3}+2 \sqrt[3]{3}}{6^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda }} = \phi(\lambda)
$$
then
$$
\phi(\lambda)^3-\lambda - c = \frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda \right)^{2/3}+2
   \sqrt[3]{3}\right)^3}{36 \left(\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda \right)}-\lambda-c
$$
or
$$
3 \left(\sqrt[3]{6} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda } \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{81
   \lambda ^2-12}+2 \sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda }+9 \sqrt[3]{2}
   \lambda \right)-6 c \left(\sqrt{81 \lambda ^2-12}+9 \lambda \right)\right)=0
$$
now making $u = \sqrt{81\lambda-12}$ we have
$$
3 \left(\sqrt[3]{6} \sqrt[3]{9 \lambda +u} \left(2 \sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt[3]{9 \lambda +u}+9
   \sqrt[3]{2} \lambda +\sqrt[3]{2} u\right)-6 c (9 \lambda +u)\right) = 0
$$
and following making $z = 9\lambda + u$ we have
$$
2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{3} z^{4/3}+2 \sqrt[3]{2} 3^{2/3} z^{2/3}-6 c z = 0
$$
and
$$
z = 9\lambda+\sqrt{81\lambda-12} = \cases{
0\\
9 c^3\pm\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 c^6-54 c^4+27 c^2-4}-9 c
}
$$
so we arrive at $\lambda = \psi(c)$ etc.

Thanks for the answer. One thing I'm uncertain about is: how do you know that $\phi$ is a function? Since the polynomial $x^3-x = \lambda$ has possibly one or three solutions, $\phi(\lambda)$ could possibly be three values.

I included a NOTE. Please have a look at. I hope it helps.
